# Is there a way to integrate custom sql query to facetwp plugin?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, facet, facetwp

I'm working on a WordPress project where I've implemented a custom search.php file with a combination of custom SQL queries and the integration of SearchWP.

Also, I am using FacetWP plugin to show facets to filter the results by post type. The issue I'm facing is that FacetWP doesn't seem to index the custom SQL query properly. When a search is performed, the sidebar facets only display content from the default WordPress query that uses integration with SearchWP.

I've reindexed FacetWP after making changes, but it seems that FacetWP isn't recognizing the custom SQL query.

make custom hooks, use js...

Comment: From the looks of it, facetwp is a commercial plugin.  I would advise you to see support from the facetwp developer, since it is a commercial product you licensed from them.